# Bootstrap - Buttons inside List Group Item

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a Web GUI, which is seperated into 2 parts: A list of different actions, implemented as a Bootstrap List Group and a detail area where settings of those actions can be changed.

Clicking on the item should display the detail/settings section for that action.

I also want quick-actions, which are small buttons on the right side of the List Group items.

This concept works in Bootstrap, but me IDE gives me warnings about the nested buttons/links. The big problem is, that this is not valid HTML5 and could lead to wrong results. An error I already noticed is, that clicking a small button also executes the list item action in Firefox.

Here is an example of the GUI concept, as this is hard to describe in words: https://jsfiddle.net/drx7xhw7/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Actions</h3>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item clearfix" onclick="alert('Action1 -> Details');">
          Action1
          <span class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick="alert('Action1 -> Play');">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item clearfix" onclick="alert('Action2 -> Details');">
          Action2
          <span class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick="alert('Action2 -> Play');">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Settings</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way of having exactly the same GUI but using valid HTML5?

Answer (score 38):

@Kim: If you still want to achieve the same with Bootstrap in the valid HTML Standard, use the following code. I changed the button to span and added the same class `btn btn-xs btn-default`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Actions</h3>
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item clearfix" onclick="alert('Action1 -> Details');">
                    Action1
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <span class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick="alert('Action1 -> Play'); event.stopPropagation();">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item clearfix" onclick="alert('Action2 -> Details');">
                    Action2
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <span class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick="alert('Action2 -> Play'); event.stopPropagation();">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Settings</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to separete click button with click tab?, I need that when I click in button only play alert is fired

Comment: @CampDev I update the code, just need to add event.stopPropagation() to the children element so that the event will not be propagated to the parents.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is near to standard bootstrap 4 list group using flex

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group cProductsList"> 
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex"><p class="p-0 m-0 flex-grow-1">First item</p> 
                   <button class="btn-success">EDIT</button>  <button class="btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                </li>
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex"><p class="p-0 m-0 flex-grow-1">Second item</p>  
                   <button class="btn-success">EDIT</button>  <button class="btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: `.justify-content-between` isn't needed on the `<li>` since you're applying `.flex-grow-1` to the `<p>`

Answer (score -1):

```
    <ul class="list-group mb-5">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">My List Item One<button class="btn-success btn-sm" style="float:right">EDIT</button>&nbsp&nbsp<button class="btn-danger btn-sm mr-2" style="float:right">DELETE</button></a>




    </ul>
```